# How do I integrate custom login on Shopify without using Multipass?

Tags: authentication, shopify

We have a website and app where our customers use our services. We are starting a new vertical and want to set up the store using Shopify and host it on a subdomain. We do not want to create a new signup/login for the Shopify site. We want to integrate the existing signup/login functionality so that there is no duplication of accounts.

Is there a way to achieve this on Shopify without using Multipass?